# If $f(x) + xf(-x) = x^2$ + 1, find what is $f(x)$?

Tags: functions, problem-solving

I'm trying to solve it by any way that I know or solving these kind of problems, but apparently such an equation has a specific way of solving. What's the point?

> If $f(x) + x f(-x) = x^2$ + 1, find what is $f(x)$ ?

or this one:

> If $f(1/x)- 2f(x) = x^2 + 1/x$, find what is $f(x)$?

Comment: Not sure what you are hoping for.  These things generally require problem specific methods.  For the first, say, note that that replacing $x$ by $-x$ yields $f(-x)-xf(x)=x^2+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the identity holds for every $x$, you can also use $-x$ to get
$$
f(-x)-xf(x)=(-x)^2+1
$$
and therefore $f(-x)=x^2+1+xf(x)$, leading to
$$
f(x)+x(x^2+1)+x^2f(x)=x^2+1
$$
and you should be able to finish.

The second one is similar: with $1/x$ instead of $x$ you get
$$
f(x)-2f(1/x)=(1/x)^2+x
$$
and now it's easy to eliminate $f(1/x)$. There is no “general method”, though.

Comment: Thanks, I could solve them now, but how should i guess that put "-x" or "1/x" or anything else? or example now I can't find anything for this one : f (x+2) + 2 f (1-x) = 4 - 3x

Comment: @WeAreBeingWatched As I said, there is no general method. For the case you show, I suggest to set $x=y-1/2$ and observe the symmetry.